# Is it ok to give an answer I'm not 100% sure on

Tags: discussion, new-users, etiquette

I see a question that I'm pretty sure I can answer but I don't want to get it wrong and have no idea how to clarify for myself.

Is it better to try and answer as best as you can or leave it in case my answer possibly misleads someone else in the future?

The particular question I've seen is mainly theoretical rather than "How do I...?" but regardless, I'm new and not sure where I stand on this matter

Comment: I can tell you that answer worded like guesses tend to get flagged so don't answer if you don't feel comfortable stating your answer without qualifiers like "I think", "Maybe", "This *might* work", etc.

Comment: Can you give/hint at the answer in a comment so that the OP can test it out?   If it's wrong, it can't be downvoted, if it's right, you can 'promote' it to an answer and, hopefully, get upvotes/accept:)   I do that a lot when I see something wrong in code but I'm not sure if that is causing the OP's stated problem.

Comment: @BSMP: flagged, for what? Not an answer? (It is.) Rude? (It is not.) If it is a *bad* answer – that is, it doesn't work at all or it does provide a valid answer but it would not work for the question – then downvote. About the only thing I can think of is that "Try this" is *obsolete* wording and may be replaced with "Use this", optionally followed by an explanation of when it would not work.

Comment: *flagged, for what? Not an answer?* @usr2564301 Yes, people will flag them as NAA. I see it regularly in the Low Quality Queue. I also see review comments on them stating "This is not an answer to the question" so it's not a false flag from the system.

Comment: @Martin James I would have left a comment but I don't have the privilege yet.  My intention as you say was to point in the right direction with the reasoning behind his question and give an example. I don't know the exact numbers or know how to test my answer, just the theory behind what he's asking, hence my indecision over giving it as an answer

Comment: @BSMP I agree with usr2564301. I think the NAA flaggers are clearly wrong in such cases.

Comment: @duplode ...OK?

Comment: @BSMP My point (which I admittedly hadn't actually stated) is that you shouldn't avoid qualifiers just because other people might mistakenly flag your answer because of them.

Comment: @duplode I made the suggestion because I have no way of knowing whether those flags normally get rejected by other reviewers or if those answers are getting deleted. That auto-review comments show up on those answers implied to me that at least some were getting deleted. I also thought that an answer getting deleted via review counted toward the answer ban.

Comment: @BSMP That's fine. It's just that, if I were in such a situation as an answerer, I'd be strongly inclined to defend my answer in the comments and, if it ended up deleted, bring the issue to Meta. (Then again, I don't know either if the situation is bad enough to make strategical adaptation/acquiescence to the mistaken reviews a tempting choice.)

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for the tip, I've delayed replying while I try to wrap my head around the replies you received (sorry usr2564301 but I still only get about half of that).  Would the system auto flag an answer that might sound noncomital due to saying "if / maybe / possibly / etc" or are we talking other users? Also I didn't realise bad answers could lead to an answer ban - I need to hit the help centre and read some rules me thinks...

Comment: I am talking about other users. As far as I know, there are no systematic checks for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should answer if you're *reasonably* confident in your solution.  It doesn't sound like you're *reasonably* confident, so I wouldn't recommend answering.

Comment: My answer goes back to something I was taught in college some 18 years ago so I'm reaching back a little and the question is a year old, I figured someone would have answered it by now.  I know technology has come a ways since then but I'm pretty sure the theory should still stand

Comment: @Rowie: so the question has not yet been answered? Then I'd favorite it and check back a few days later. It could be nobody has a clue where to start, and so even a partial answer may lead to someone else thinking, "ah wait a minute..." But keep in mind this could also indicate the question itself is too broad or unclear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987537/what-is-a-real-life-example-of-detrimental-code-explosion-caused-by-field-initia  The answer isn't so much unclear just being looked from too close up, it's to do with exponensial code growth so I'm 99% sure the answer is in what happens when you nest the object in his example.  I wouldn't mind answering so much if I knew it could be reviewed and corrected first but I'm not even sure who to ask

Comment: @Rowie On the specific question you are talking about, it actually has two answers which were deleted after having been shown to be wrong through the comments. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRLxE.png), in case you want to have a look at them.

Comment: @duplode Thanks for that, I thought it odd it had no answers.  From my understanding the first answer is pretty close though, the code is only injected into the beggining of relevent constructors - had they not been chained (eg if the class was created entirely given one set of values or another) the variables would have been injected into all of them